# How to choose the region/availability zone when buying an AWS Reserved Instance?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-reserved-instances

This is the page where I can buy a Reserved Instance:

[image]

I can click *Add to Cart*, but then how do I know in which region/AZ is the RI?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The instances are reserved in whichever region your console was set to when you initiated the purchase:

[image]

You can also click on the "Only show offerings that reserve capacity" (shown) if you want to purchase [Zonal-scoped RIs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/reserved-instances-scope.html).

Answer (score 1):

Before you click on "Purchased Reserved Instances" you are in the EC2 console under a specific region and this is the region you are buying in.  If you want to select a different region, change your region by clicking the Region name in the top-right banner of the AWS console.

Normally, reserved instances can be used in any AZ.  If you want to reserve capacity in an AZ and lock in the RI into a specific AZ, click the checkbox labeled "Only Show Offerings that reserve capacity" in top-right of the Purchase Reserved Instance dialogue/search box and you will see listing for specific AZs.